# bcrypt.compare function providing correct results for different genSalt values while hashing

Tags: hash, compare, bcrypt

In my side-project, I found a way to hash the password using 'bcrypt' package with syntax like:
  `const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,salt);`

And for comparison, the syntax is like:
`const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password,hashedpassword);`

And this seems to compare the passwords properly, even when I change the genSalt value while hashing from 10 to 12 or some other value.
but I am unable to understand the working behind the compare function since we did not specify the genSalt value, so how does it automatically find that the passwords are same or not?

I tried multiple values in genSalt function and it worked for all of them.

Comment: Give the complete code of the two cases that have you confused, and explain what you think *should* happen. It's unclear to me what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My confusion is 'Say I am the getting the salt using: bcrypt.getSalt(10) function, if I change the value from 10 to 20 and hash password and save to DB, how does the compare function, bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword) gets to know the salt value which was used in generating salt, since the only params for compare function are 1) the password with which user is trying to login  2) the hashed password in Database.' I think in the compare function, we should be passing at least 1 more parameter which must be salt value that we chose while generating salt.

Comment: The salt is encoded in the hashed password. The 'hashed password' includes a hash algorithm identifier plus the salt plus the actual raw hashed password.